# Apply masking on selective image regions using opencv python

Tags: python-3.x, mask, opencv, python

I have an ML model that I am using to create a mask to separate background and object. The problem is that the model is not that accurate and we still get regions of background around the edges.

The background could be any color but it is not uniform as you can see in the image.

[image]

This is the model output.

[image]

I was wondering if there is a way I could apply masking only around the edges so it doesn't affect other parts of the object which have been extracted properly. Basically I only want to trim down these edges which contain the background so any solutions using python are appreciated.

I'm really sorry for not being at the liberty to share the code but I'm only looking for ideas that I can implement to solve this problem.

Comment: Does the model output the mask as well?

Comment: It does output the mask. I posted this image for better understanding.

Comment: Pure image processing approach to background subtraction is very hard when the background has shadows and/or is similar in color to the foreground object. The best approaches these days use AI/Deep Learning with lots of training. See http://remove.bg

Answer (score 0):

You can use binary erosion or dilation to "grow" the mask so that it covers the edge
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_dilation.html
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_erosion.html

as for "apply masking only around the edges" (this is not the same mask I was writing about above), you can flag pixels that are close to the edge by iteration over a mask and finding where there is a `0` that has a neighbouring `1` or vice versa.